# This boolean loop keeps repeating?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, boolean

For this section of code shown below, I need it to loop back to the beginning as it already is, if someone doesn't input a double, but after it proceeds to the next portion of the program, the loop is still going. How can I fix this?

```
public static void cat()
{
    boolean loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        //read in name from user as a string
        // read in first number from user as a string
        name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the model of the first car.");
        firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the price of the first car.");
        repair1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the price of the repairs for the first car.");

        // read in second number from user as a string
        name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the model of the second car.");
        secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the price of the second car.");
        repair2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the price of the repairs for the second car.");

        // read in third number from user as a string
        name3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the model of the third car.");
        thirdNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the price of the third car.");
        repair3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the price of the repairs for the third car.");

        // read in forth number from user as a string        
        check();
    } // convert numbers from type String to type int
}

public static void check()
{
    try
    {
        number1 = Double.parseDouble (firstNumber);
        number2 = Double.parseDouble (secondNumber);
        number3 = Double.parseDouble (thirdNumber);
        Repair1 = Double.parseDouble (repair1);
        Repair2 = Double.parseDouble (repair2);
        Repair3 = Double.parseDouble (repair3);
        tax1 = number1 * 0.13;
        tax2 = number2 * 0.13;
        tax3 = number3 * 0.13;
        total1 = number1 + tax1 - Repair1;
        total2 = number2 + tax2 - Repair2;
        total3 = number3 + tax3 - Repair3;
        tc1 = Double.toString (total1);
        tc2 = Double.toString (total2);
        tc3 = Double.toString (total3);

        // display the results
        Chapter4 mainFrame = new Chapter4 ();
        mainFrame.setVisible (true);

        //System.exit (0);  // terminate the program
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,
                "Error: You have to enter a car price!",
                "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } //end try/catch block
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "after it proceeds to the next portion of the program"?

Comment: Where the heck do you change `loop` inside the while loop??? How is the while loop going to stop if the control variable is never changed??? This isn't a programming or a Java question but rather a simple logic question, and to solve this you will want to simply walk through your code mentally, and the problem will become obvious to you.

Comment: I don't see `loop` changing anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You should change `loop` value, or the while loop will repeat infinitely.

Make `check` return `boolean` and loop inside `cat`until `check` returns `true`.

```
public static void cat() 
{
    boolean loop = true;

    while (loop) 
    {
        //read in name from user as a string
        // read in first number from user as a string
        name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the model of the first car.");
        firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the first car.");
        repair1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the repairs for the first car.");

        // read in second number from user as a string
        name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the model of the second car.");
        secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the second car.");
        repair2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the repairs for the second car.");

        // read in third number from user as a string
        name3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the model of the third car.");
        thirdNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the third car.");
        repair3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the repairs for the third car.");

        // read in forth number from user as a string
        loop = !check();
    } // convert numbers from type String to type int
}

public static boolean check() 
{
    try 
    {
        number1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber);
        number2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        number3 = Double.parseDouble(thirdNumber);
        Repair1 = Double.parseDouble(repair1);
        Repair2 = Double.parseDouble(repair2);
        Repair3 = Double.parseDouble(repair3);
        tax1 = number1 * 0.13;
        tax2 = number2 * 0.13;
        tax3 = number3 * 0.13;
        total1 = number1 + tax1 - Repair1;
        total2 = number2 + tax2 - Repair2;
        total3 = number3 + tax3 - Repair3;
        tc1 = Double.toString(total1);
        tc2 = Double.toString(total2);
        tc3 = Double.toString(total3);

        // display the results
        Chapter4 mainFrame = new Chapter4();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        //System.exit (0);  // terminate the program
        return true;
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Error: You have to enter a car price!",
            "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } //end try/catch block
    return false;
}
```

---

Or as @pbabcdefp suggested, make it a `do..while` loop. It's a perfect use case and you avoid usage of the `loop` variable completely:

```
public static void cat() 
{
    do 
    {
        //read in name from user as a string
        // read in first number from user as a string
        name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the model of the first car.");
        firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the first car.");
        repair1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the repairs for the first car.");

        // read in second number from user as a string
        name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the model of the second car.");
        secondNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the second car.");
        repair2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the repairs for the second car.");

        // read in third number from user as a string
        name3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the model of the third car.");
        thirdNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the third car.");
        repair3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price of the repairs for the third car.");

        // read in forth number from user as a string
    } while(!check()); // convert numbers from type String to type int
}
```

Comment: Or better still, get rid of `loop` and use `do { ... } while (!check());`

Comment: @pbabcdefp I agree it would be better, but this seems to be the simplest change to OP's code and I didn't want to make it too complicated or confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not updating the loop variable. While adding code to update that would solve your problem, here's another approach. Change the code so that your `check()` function throws the exception instead of catching it. Then, catch it in the `cat()` function to exit the loop.

eg:

```
public static void check() throws NumberFormatException {
    //code here, get rid of the try block inside
}
```

Update main `cat()` as well:

```
public static void cat() {
    try {
        while (loop) {
            // other code here
            check();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // handle it
    }
}
```

If you're doing it like this though, you may as well get rid of the loop variable and change it to `while (true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to interpret but I'll give it a swing.

you're looping based off of the variable "loop" which equals true. to break out of the loop, you need to change the value of the loop to false at some point

Comment: How does one change a local variable out of it's scope?